# Creating UTC time in momentjs is returning weird results

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am tearing my hear off on a Monday evening! Can anyone please help me understand the problem below? 
I have the following string on my browser `01-09-2014` (this is in local time), I want to convert this into UTC so that I can save that back to the server.
Here is what I am doing:

```
    var localDate = moment("01-09-2014", "DD-MM-YYYY");
    var utcDate = localDate.utc();
    console.log("Local Date " + localDate.toDate() + " UTC Date " + utcDate.toDate());
```

Strangely enough, the last line outputs:

```
Local Date Mon Sep 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time) UTC Date Mon Sep 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)
```

**QUESTION**

- Why does the UTC date look exactly the same as the local one (I expect the local time to be 2 hours ahead of UTC given I am in an GMT+2 zone) ?
- Why does the UTC date have GMT+0200? I expect a UTC date to have GMT+000

Could you please help me with these two questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thoug I am not sure about ... but I think it should be:

```
var utcDate = localDate.utc().format()
```

See:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

**UPDATED**

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qhk9tnLr/2/

JS:

```
console.log("Local Date: " + moment("01-09-2014", "DD-MM-YYYY").toDate());
console.log("UTC Date: " + moment("01-09-2014", "DD-MM-YYYY").utc().format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss zZZ"));
```

Output:

```
Local Date: Mon Sep 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200
UTC Date: Sun Aug 31 2014 22:00:00 UTC+0000
```

Conclusion:

`toDate()` will give the local time - to get UTC use `utc().format()`

Comment: thanks for the answer, format outputs a string, what I want is a javascript date object. Even worse, format returns a date string that is one day behind 8-)

Comment: Yeah - but you will get the desired value with it ... see my updated answer :)

Comment: @GETah - a JS `Date` object is *always* going to use the time zone of the local computer.  As soon as you call `toDate()`, you're undoing the effect of moment's `utc` function.  You can't pass a `Date` object to the server anyway.  Ultimately, you'll have to format it as a string, so you should just use moment's `format` or `toISOString` functions.

Comment: Hm this gets more interesting... now even the local date's GMT offset is set to 0 `Local Date 2014-08-31T22:00:00+00:00 UTC Date 2014-08-31T22:00:00+00:00` Any idea why this happens?